# Autocomplete suggestion input box filled with bar code scanner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I was trying to implement autocomplete search where i will write something and related data will show up in autocomplete search but i want to filled the input box with bar code scanner input as well. When input box filled with scanner it will suggest the related data. But the problem i'm facing here while i write something it shows the related data but when bar code scanning output filled in input box, it doesn't suggest .. How do i implement that?

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" required autofocus  class="form-control m-input" id="customerSearch" placeholder="Customer name">
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
    $('#customerSearch').autocomplete({
       source: '{!! asset('customerSearch') !!}',
       select: function(suggestion,ui) {
           // $("#customer_id").val(ui.item.id);           
       }
    })
```

Comment: Could you show us your complete code? HTML and JS

Comment: Updated with code

Comment: What and where is your barcode input?

Comment: after scanning, it will automatically posted in inputbox .it may be text ..doesn't matter .

Comment: Does it trigger an `input` event when it is "automatically" posted in the input box??

Comment: nothing triggered or i'm not sure how to trigger some event when input box been filled with bar code scanner input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofocus is triggered on keydown event, so code scanner won't trigger it.
You must trigger the event yourself after input is changed.
Try this:

```
  $('#customerSearch').on('input', function(){
     $('#customerSearch').trigger('keydown');
  });
```

Comment: Just asking where to put that code. i'm not getting

Comment: You can check this fiddle, the button is working as the scanner. You can try the events in order to trigger the keydown:
https://jsfiddle.net/ed7mv1n9/26/

Answer (score 0):

### Insertion of a value into an input does not trigger events

I would suggest trying the following to trigger an event, if it works the event should then trigger the jQuery autocomplete to update.

Create an event:

```
const event = new Event('keydown')
```

Then dispatch this event:

```
customerSearch.dispatchEvent(event)
```

This is also possible with jQuery:

```
jQuery('#customerSearch').trigger('keydown')
// or
$('#customerSearch').trigger('keydown')
```

---

You'll want to trigger/dispatch the event after your code scanner has changed the input value. That would look something like this:

```
customerSearch.value = codeScannerValue
// or however it actually works

$('#customerSearch').trigger('keydown')
// or
customerSearch.dispatchEvent(new Event('keydown'))
```